# jOptionPane dont show on top windows. Java 1.4

Tags: java, windows, joptionpane, java1.4, always-on-top

jOptionPane dont show on top windows.

I've read that using

```
JFrame frmOpt = new JFrame();
frmOpt.setVisible(true);
frmOpt.setLocation(100, 100);
frmOpt.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

should be enough, but the problems is that I'm using Java 1.4 and 'setAlwaysOnTop' does not exists.

so....is there a way to solve this situation?

thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is what I'm doing:

```
           JFrame frmOpt = new JFrame();
           frmOpt.setVisible(false);
           response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frmOpt,message,mens, 0,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,null,options,null);
```

First I create a JFrame, then I create a new JOptionFrame setting the JFrame.

And it still shows at the back. Notice I do not use setAlwaysOnTop because of Java 1.4

Comment: There's not enough code, as you speak of JOptionPane but describe JFrame. Usually, JOptionPane will automatically show in front by specifying the frame as parent of the JOptionPane in one of its many show* methods.

Comment: I do declare the JOptionPanel, notice the edit. thanks

Comment: If your goal is to just show the message and the frame is only there for the purpose of passing the first argument into the first parameter `parent` of `showOptionDialog()`, please note that `showOptionDialog()` happily accepts a `null` parent, and usually this will cause the `JOptionPane` to appear in the front. In case your `JFrame frmOpt` is used for other purposes as well, you might as well call `frmOpt.toFront()` first. But please note that the layering of a Dialog onto a front-most but invisible Frame might be platform-specific behavior.

Comment: I've tried to set null in the first argument, in fact was my first try, but if I do so, the JPane appears behind the client. That's why I tried creating a JFrame or anything that would make it work. With the JFrame I made it appear at the front, but also appears the JFrame itself with nothing else than the red cross to close it

Comment: Is the client another JFrame of the same application or is the client a different application?

Comment: the client is Internet Explorer, a requirement of the application.